# Python Error:"TypeError: string indices must be integers"

Tags: python, json, pyodbc

I'm here trying to parse JSON string that comes from a sql table, but while parsing it is giving the error `TypeError: string indices must be integers` at line `result = json_normalize(json_st,'results')`

here is the code snippet

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
import pyodbc
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('connection string')
cursor = cnxn.cursor()

cursor.execute("select TOP 1 GEOCODE_ID, JSON from GEOCODE_TBL where GEOCODE_ID = 20")
ID=[]
JSON=[]

for row in cursor.fetchall():
      ID.append(row[0])
      JSON.append(row[1])


json_st1 = json.dumps(JSON)
json_st=json.loads(json_st1)

result = json_normalize(json_st,'results')
```

Any suggestion on this will be helpful.

Thanks

Domnick.

Comment: try to print `row[0`] and `row[1]` and see what they are , you can  use enumerate and use index no there.

Comment: @AyodhyankitPaul row[0] gives me the ID and row[1] the json string which is of type str `type(row[1])
Out[119]: str`

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the function signature, it takes one **data** variable and some optional params.

```
pandas.io.json.json_normalize(data, record_path=None, meta=None, 
meta_prefix=None, record_prefix=None, errors='raise', sep='.')
```

Where `data : dict or list of dicts`. So you can't pass it as a **string**. Also, why are you passing the string `'results'` too?

Your data variable needs to be a dict, or list of dicts (which is, json in python)